# How to override attributes in validate annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I have custom annotation, like this:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String message() default "message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And validator in order to validate stuff:

```
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyAnnotation myAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ConstraintValidatorContextImpl con = (ConstraintValidatorContextImpl)context;

        String diff = getDiff(value, cleanForHTMLContext(value));
        if(diff.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private cleanForHTMLContext(String value) {
       // Some stuff to clean up value
    }

    private String getDiff(String value, String cleanedValue) {
       // Some stuff to compare values
    }
}
```

My goal is to add **"diff" to annotation attributes**, then later have possibility to resolve message by key and attributes from ResourceBundle.

As example: when use type invalid date, it should see the folloiwng message:

**Data invalid, because contain this text: {diff}.** Where diff will be runtime comparison result between two strings that will be evaluated in **isValid()** method.

I have tried to ovverrite value from map arguments like this:

```
ConstraintValidatorContextImpl con = (ConstraintValidatorContextImpl)context;
con.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes().put("diff", value);
```

But unfortunatly I got exception regarding unmodifible map that are created in `ConstraintDescriptorImpl`

Is any other possibility to add custom attributes that will be resolved then with error code?

Answer (score 4):

Just tried this myself, the solution below works if you are using Hibernate Validator. Note your message must include `${}` to mark the variable parts, not `{}`.

```
private MyAnnotation annotation;

@Override
public void initialize(MyAnnotation a)
{
    this.annotation = a;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx)
{
    String diff = getDiff(value, cleanForHTMLContext(value));
    if (diff.isEmpty())
        return true;

    String message = annotation.message();
    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hctx = ctx.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);

    ctx.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    ctx.addExpressionVariable("diff", diff)
       .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
       .addConstraintViolation();
    return false;
}
```

Note your message should contain `${diff}` as template, not `{diff}`.

```
...
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String message() default "Data invalid, because contain this text: ${diff}.";
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, I've already tried such thing, but forgot to specify. Unfortunatly it does not work in my case. The main pain that I work with BindingResult object that subsequently converted to CustomObject to have possibility resolve message on Client Side.

Comment: When I tried to validate object with MyCustomAnnotation message "Data invalid, because contain this text: {diff}." will be set to defaultMessage field of that object. And in this case I don't know exactly when to extract message from that field. As example when field validated by Length hibernate annotation it will be automatically set default message to BindingResult.

Comment: I extended the answer to contain the full `isValid()` method. Hopefully this makes it clearer. I don't know the 'proper' way to do the template replacement, but included a suggestion for an alternative (cleaner) way which may or may not work.

Comment: I changed my answer. It now contains a proper way to substitute templates, using the Hibernate framework.

Comment: Unfortunatly it also does not work for me, because this feature use to resolve message with attributes on hibernate side, please correct me if I am wrong. My goal is to have separetly attributes and error keys in spring BindingResult object as these stuff will be resolved on client side.